# how to get many to many relationship data in laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
Suppliers table

id | name

1  | supplier1

2  | supplier2
```

```
Products table

id | name

1  | product1

2  | product2
```

```
Attributes table

id | name

1  | width

2  | heigh

3  | weight

4  | volume
```

```
supplier_product table

supplier_id | product_id | price

1           | 1          | 1000

1           | 2          | 1500

2           | 1          | 1100
```

```
attribute_product

supplier_id | product_id | attribute_id | value

1           | 1          | 1            | 10

1           | 1          | 2            | 15

1           | 1          | 3            | 20

1           | 2          | 1            | 11

1           | 2          | 2            | 16

2           | 1          | 1            | 10

2           | 1          | 2            | 13
```

How to get attribute for each product for each supplier?

Comment: Why `attribute_product` has a column `supplier_id`? Attributes are linked to the product and the product is linked to the supplier, Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasManyThrough` relationship (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) as long as you modify the structure of your tables.

**Supplier Model**

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Attribute', 'App\Product');
}
```